# Adding the social likes values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add social likes values(Twitter,Facebook,GooglePlus,Pinterest,emailaccount) using jquery. This is my html code.

```
<div class="social-likes">
<span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet' st_via=""></span>
<span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_vcount' displayText='Share'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_vcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email_vcount' displayText='Email'></span>

<span id="total_shares"></span> // Display the total
</div>
```

and here is the jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var TweetCount    = jQuery('.st_twitter_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').text();
var FacebookCount   = jQuery('.st_facebook_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').text();
var GooglePlusCount = jQuery('.st_googleplus_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').text();
var PinInterestCount= jQuery('.st_pinterest_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').text();
var EmailCount    = jQuery('.st_email_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').text();
var TotalShares   = parseInt(TweetCount) + parseInt(FacebookCount) + parseInt(GooglePlusCount) + parseInt(PinInterestCount) + parseInt(EmailCount);
jQuery('#total_shares').text(TotalShares );
Alert(TotalShares);

</script>
```

When I try in inspect each element on a browser, the codes are these.

```
<span class="st_twitter_vcount" st_via="" displaytext="Tweet" st_processed="yes">
 <span class="stButton" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline- block;cursor:pointer;">
  <div>
    <div style="display: block;" class="stBubble">
        <div class="stBubble_count">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </span>
```

```
<span class="st_facebook_vcount" displaytext="Tweet" st_processed="yes">
 <span class="stButton" style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline- block;cursor:pointer;">
  <div>
    <div style="display: block;" class="stBubble">
        <div class="stBubble_count">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </span>
```

.... and other...

But when I tried to put alert into the script, It returns an Undefined value(NaN). Did I missed something? please help me I am new on jquery/javascript. My goal is something like this. http://mashable.com/2013/11/05/voice-impressions-video/  . Getting the total shares.

Comment: What is getting assigned to TweetCount, FacebookCount, etc? Also, are the '.stBubble' and '.stBubble_count' class selectors necessary?

Comment: where is `stBubble` & `stBubble_count` elements ????

Comment: Your HTML does not contain any numbers that could be read and parsed.

Comment: I updated my question. Yes. Id doesn't contain any elements. I think its on inner HTML.

Comment: try this `jQuery('.st_twitter_vcount .stBubble .stBubble_count').html()` ... use `html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: I've tried that but it returns an Undefined value.

Comment: place your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ..your code should be here.. })`